# setLatestEventInfo Can not resolve in api 23+

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

am using [Androidexample.com psuh notificaion](http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139) am new to android am getting error to setLatestEventInfo, I found solution that method is setLatestEventInfo() was removed from the SDK in Android 6.0. please help below is the code

private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

```
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    notification.sound = Uri.parse(
    "android.resource://"
            + context.getPackageName()
            + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to : https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes/android.app.Notification.html

This method was removed in M (api 23). So if your compile SDK version is set to api 23+ you'll see this issue.

Thereofore try this:

```
 private void raiseNotification(String mimeType, File output,
                                 Exception e) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder b=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    b.setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

    if (e == null) {
      b.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.download_complete))
       .setContentText(getString(R.string.fun))
       .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download_done)
       .setTicker(getString(R.string.download_complete));

      Intent outbound=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

      outbound.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(output), mimeType);

      b.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, outbound, 0));
    }
    else {
      b.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.exception))
       .setContentText(e.getMessage())
       .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
       .setTicker(getString(R.string.exception));
    }

    NotificationManager mgr=
        (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ID, b.build());
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for you quick response, can you please suggest correction or changes in my above code

Comment: use NotificationCompat.Builder. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html

Answer (score 1):

After hour & hour work i come to solution...am so happy today !!!
if any one want's compleate code for GCM push notification you can email me sandeepautade2@gmail.com

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
       long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

        b.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setTicker("Hearty365")
                .setContentTitle("Default notification")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setContentInfo("Info");


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, b.build());

    }
```